# Make ruby script use local gems, instead of common

Tags: ruby, bundle

I'm deploying my rails project to production server. There is only 1.9.3 version of ruby (I developed on 2.1.2) so there is few compatibility problems in gems versions. More over, I downloaded one of gems to vendor/gem_name and made necessary fixes in its sources, so I need to use exactly my version of that gem and, as you understand, It's not possible to update it.

in Gemfile

```
require 'gem_name', :path => 'vendor/gem_name'
```

So after cloning project to server I run

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

and it created bundle directory in vendor folder with gems versions, needed to me, inside it.

After that I tried to run fetching script to fill db with some data by command

```
ruby *_fetch.rb
```

inside *_fetch.rb:

```
require 'gem_name'
```

And it fails with error

> You have already activated gem_name *older_version*, but your Gemfile requires
>   gem_name *newest_version*. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'

So how could I specify script to require my edited local gem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run it with `bundle exec` That's exactly what `bundle exec` is for.

Comment: I've already tried that. 'bundle exec data_fetch.rb' outputs:
bundler: command not found: zpinfo_fetch.rb
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`

Running bundle install completes with 'Your bundle is complete!
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle'

Comment: Did you try `bundle exec ruby data_fetch.rb`?